# How do I match all URL paths that do not start with /web?

Tags: regex, apache

We have a LocationMatch that we are using to regex match url path's.

We have a directive that loads a dispatcher module, if the url does not start with '/web'. So, we want to have it match:

```
/web
/web/application
```

We do not want it to match:

```
/site
/webapps
/webapps/application
```

I am kind of at a loss, both because I am still somewhat new to regex, but also because I do not know exactly what to search for.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Something like

`^/web(/.*)?$`

should do the trick. You can read it this way:

- `^` means the string starts here
- `/web` is the part you're looking for
- `(` here starts a group
- `/.*` a slash followed by any number of charachters (even 0)
- `)` here ends the group
- `?` means that whatever was before it (our group) may or may not be there
- `$` means the string ends here.

This basically matches /web, /web/, and /web/whatever.

You can use [this website](https://www.debuggex.com/) to understand how the regex works:

Answer (score 4):

To match all URL paths that do not start with /web or /site, or /webapps use

```
^/(?!web|site|webapps)(.*)$
```

Comment: this will match /webapps

Comment: ?! exclude web, site and webapps with the character | for OR